# Artifactory: Migrate massive amounts of binary data of sharepoint to artifactory?

Tags: sharepoint, artifactory

What is the fastest and efficient method to transfer massive amounts of binary data into artifactory repos from a windows sharepoint?

Currently My idea is to leverage on PS script and include some jfrog CLI.

is that the best method or any other better SOPs?
thanks!!

leverage on PS script.